# Tensorboard callback not writing the training metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, tf.keras

When the model is taking sufficiently long to infer (i.e. enough parameters and data big enough), and when `profile_batch` is on, the `TensorBoard` callback fails to write the training metrics to the log events (at least they are not visible in Tensorboard).

Here is the code used to get that failure:

```py
import os.path as op
import time

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

size = 512
im = Input((size, size, 1))
im_conv = Conv2D(512, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(im)
im_conv = Conv2D(1, 3, padding='same', activation='linear')(im_conv)
model = Model(im, im_conv)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

data = np.random.rand(1, size, size, 1)

run_id = f'{int(time.time())}'
log_dir = op.join('logs', run_id)
tboard_cback = TensorBoard(
    log_dir=log_dir, 
    histogram_freq=0, 
    write_graph=False, 
    write_images=False, 
    profile_batch=2,
)

model.fit(
    x=data, 
    y=data, 
    validation_data=[data, data], 
    callbacks=[tboard_cback,], 
    epochs=100, 
    verbose=0,
);
```

Here is the Tensorboard viz I have: [image: tensorboard_viz]

Is there something wrong with the way I am using this callback?

I use Python 3.6.8, `tensorflow` 2.0.0 on GPU (but the behaviour is the same on CPU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, this is due to the profiling done in the callback. We can disable it via `profile_batch=0`. The issue is ongoing and to be followed here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2084